# Can't rotate a Unity GameObject created with code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity noob question:  I created an empty game object and attached the following script.  It creates an analog clock face with 12 tics on it and I would like it to rotate.  Although I can see the 'empty' game object rotation changing in the inspector, the clock face rotation stays at zero, and the tics associated with the rotation don't move.  I tried to "force" the clockFace to rotate in the update method: but in the Unity inspector, I see no changes in the transform in the inspector and the tics don't move.  I must be missing something very fundamental...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using UnityEngine;



public class AnalogClockTics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numTics = 12; // The number of tics to create
    public float roseDiameter = 5f;
    public float ticLength = 0.5f; // The length of each tic
    public float ticWidth = 0.05f; // The width of each tic
    public GameObject clockFace; // The clock face object that the tics will be placed on


    private LineRenderer[] tics; // Array to hold the Line Renderer components of the tics

    private void Start()
    {
        // Create an array to hold the tics
        tics = new LineRenderer[numTics];
            //This will make the clock face object a child of the "compass rose" game object, and position it at the local origin of the parent.
            GameObject clockFace = new GameObject("Clock Face");
            clockFace.transform.SetParent(transform);
            //clockFace.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        // Loop through the number of tics to create
        for (int i = 0; i < numTics; i++)
        {

            // Create a new GameObject to hold the tic
            GameObject ticObj = new GameObject("Tic " + i);
            ticObj.transform.SetParent(clockFace.transform); // Set the parent of the tic to the clock face object

            // Add a Line Renderer component to the tic GameObject
            LineRenderer ticLR = ticObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
            ticLR.startWidth = ticWidth;
            ticLR.endWidth = ticWidth;

            // Calculate the angle of the tic
            float angle = i * 360f / numTics;

            float angleInRadians = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            Vector3 startPos = clockFace.transform.position + new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians), Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians), 0f) * (roseDiameter - ticLength);

            Vector3 endPos = startPos + new Vector3(
                Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 
                Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 
                0f
                ) * ticLength;

            // Set the positions of the Line Renderer
            ticLR.SetPositions(new Vector3[] { startPos, endPos });

            // Add the Line Renderer to the tics array
            tics[i] = ticLR;
        }
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // rotates this (empty) game object which in turn should rotate the clock face
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0.05f, Space.Self);
        clockFace.transform.SetParent(transform);
        // clockFace.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0.05f, Space.Self);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code

- You should get a loud exception every frame about `clockFace` not being assigned.

  This is due to you in `Start` using a local variable with the same name

  ```
  GameObject clockFace = new GameObject("Clock Face");
  ```

  this "hides" your class field `clockFace` which will therefore remain unassigned.

  => You rather want to either assign your class field instead of creating a new local variable:

  ```
  clockFace = new GameObject("Clock Face");
  ```

  or actually stick to the local variable .. you don't need the class field at all (see below)
- By default the `LineRenderer` uses `positions` in **world-space**!

  No matter where you move or rotate your tic options it has no effect whatsoever on the used world space positions.

  => You rather want to use **local-space** positions and therefore set

  ```
  ticLR.useWorldSpace = false;
  ...
  var startPos = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians), Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians), 0f) * (roseDiameter - ticLength);
  ```
- In general since you nest your objects and rotate only the parent object it makes sense that in the `Inspector` you only see the rotation change for the parent object. The rotation displayed in the Inspector is the `localRotation` which doesn't change -  and is not supposed to - in your code.
- Currently you rotate with `0.05` degree **per frame**!

  You rather want a frame-rate independent rotation **per-second**.

  => Therefore you should multiply the value by [`https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) and now rather use a proper angle per seconds e.g. `0.1` to have the clock perform a full `360°` rotation within 1 hour.

Two further side-notes:

- Setting the parent **once** is enough. There is no need to repeat this in every frame.
- Not sure what you need the `tics` array for, currently it isn't really used anyway.

---

So all together something like e.g.

```
public class AnalogClockTics : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip(" The number of tics to create")]
    public int numTics = 12;
    [Tooltip("Diameter of the clock rose")]
    public float roseDiameter = 5f;
    [Tooltip("The length of each tic")]
    public float ticLength = 0.5f;
    [Tooltip("The width of each tic")]
    public float ticWidth = 0.05f;
    [Tooltip("Rotation speed in angle per second")]
    public float anglePerSecond = 0.1f;
    [Tooltip("Material to use for the tics")]
    public Material ticMaterial;

    private LineRenderer[] _tics;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Do you need this at all?
        _tics = new LineRenderer[numTics];

        var clockFace = new GameObject("Clock Face");
        clockFace.transform.SetParent(transform);

        for (var i = 0; i < numTics; i++)
        {
            var ticObj = new GameObject("Tic " + i);
            ticObj.transform.SetParent(clockFace.transform);

            var ticLR = ticObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
            ticLR.startWidth = ticWidth;
            ticLR.endWidth = ticWidth;

            // Set to use local space
            ticLR.useWorldSpace = false;

            // Set proper material
            ticLR.material = ticMaterial;

            var angle = i * 360f / numTics;
            var angleInRadians = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

            // Position now in local space!
            var startPos = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angleInRadians), Mathf.Cos(angleInRadians), 0f) * (roseDiameter - ticLength);

            var endPos = startPos + new Vector3(
                Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad),
                Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad),
                0f
            ) * ticLength;

            // Make sure the position count is correct
            ticLR.positionCount = 2;

            ticLR.SetPositions(new[] { startPos, endPos });
            _tics[i] = ticLR;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Used a faster angle per second for demo ;)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear, thorough and concise answer!  The video was a very nice touch.